# Visual Studio shows warning C6330: 'char' passed as _Param_(1) when 'unsigned char' is required in call to 'isdigit'. when I try to build

Tags: c++

This is only a small part from my code. What I'm trying to do is writing at the end of the file (add record) which in this case is "books.txt" that already has 40 records. But when I debug, it would still prompt the user to enter isbn code but after entering, (process 3296) exited with code 3. came out. Which part am I doing wrong? The counter() function is to count how many records I already have in my file. And I'm also using array of struct to store my records.

```
int add_record(DATA book[])
{
    int count = counter();
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t      : :Add Book Record: :\n\n";
    bool cont;

    ofstream outfile("books.txt", ios::app);
    if (outfile.is_open() && !outfile.eof())
    {

        do
        {
            cont = true;
            cout << "ISBN Code: ";
            cin.getline(book[++count].isbn_code, 14, '\n');
            //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            int length = strlen(book[++count].isbn_code);
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
            {
                if (!isdigit(book[++count].isbn_code[i]))
                {
                    cont = false;
                    cout << "Your input is invalid. Enter again.\n";
                    break;
                }

            }
        } while (cont == false);

        do
        {
            cont = true;
            cout << "Author: ";
            cin.getline(book[++count].author, 50, '\n');
            int length = strlen(book[++count].author);
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
            {
                if (isdigit(book[++count].author[i]))
                {
                    cont = false;
                    cout << "Your input is invalid. Enter again.\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (cont == false);
          outfile << book[++count].isbn_code << "," << book[++count].author ;
          outfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File is not open\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the error message is completely correct. This is a rare case where using a cast is the correct thing to do

```
if (isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(book[++count].author[i])))
```

Reference, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

But this has nothing to do with your crash which is caused by other errors. For instance

```
        cin.getline(book[++count].isbn_code, 14, '\n');
        //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        int length = strlen(book[++count].isbn_code);
```

You definitely don't want to increment `count` twice. I would guess the correct code is

```
        cin.getline(book[count].isbn_code, 14, '\n');
        int length = strlen(book[count].isbn_code);
```

and to increment `count` once later in your loop.

Remember `++count` is not the same as `count + 1`. The first increments the `count` variable, that is it changes the value of the `count` variable, but `count + 1` just adds one to `count` and does not change the value of the `count` variable.

This is also wrong

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
```

In C++ string indexes start at zero and go upto the length of the string **minus one**, so the correct code is

```
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

Also not part of your question but `X` can be a legal character in an ISBN.